# Using ant tasks from gradle-script-kotlin

Tags: ant, kotlin, patch, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How can I access ant tasks from my `build.gradle.kts` script? In particular, I am interested in the `ant.patch` task.

Can I extend it, like so?

```
task("patchSources", Patch::class) {
```

Can I invoke it from other task, like this?

```
task("patchSources") {
    doLast {
        ant.patch(...)
    }
}
```

I know how to do it in Groovy: [How do I apply a patch file in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064086/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-file-in-gradle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```kotlin
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Patch

val patchConfigTask = task("patchConfig") {
    dependsOn(unzipTask)    

    doLast {
        val resources = projectDir.resolve("src/main/resources")
        val patchFile = resources.resolve("config.patch")

        Patch().apply {
            setPatchfile(patchFile)
            setDir(buildDir.resolve("config/"))
            setStrip(1)  // gets rid of the a/ b/ prefixes
            execute()
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if it's the one-right-way-to-do-it.

Comment: This was helpful to know how to use the Zip task from Groovy with @CompileStatic as well.

Answer (score 3):

[`AntBuilder`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/AntBuilder.html) extends from Groovy's [`AntBuilder`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.12/html/gapi/groovy/util/AntBuilder.html). You can translate the dynamic method invocations from groovy like `ant.patch()` to Kotlin by using `invokeMethod` and providing the desired task as the first argument and the properties to bind as a map in the second argument.

For example, for your *Patch* use case ([available properties documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/patch.html)) the Kotlin could look like this:

```kotlin
val patchSources by tasks.creating {
  doLast {
    ant.invokeMethod("patch", mapOf(
        "patchfile" to patchFile,
        "dir" to configDir,
        "strip" to 1
    ))
  }
}
```